# How to set GRADLE_USER_HOME in VSCode?

Tags: gradle, visual-studio-code

**Environment**
Operating System: Windows 10
JDK version: Java 1.8
Visual Studio Code version:1.42.1
Java extension pack version:0.8.1  <==plugin for supporting java

Hi, 
I would like to enquire how to set GRADLE_USER_HOME in VSCode, so that the libs' path displayed under the Project and External Dependencies node of the JAVA DEPENDENCIES section is showing the path value set in the GRADE_USER_HOME.

I learnt about java.import.gradle.arguments and java.import.gradle.jvmArguments settings which i can set in the workspace settings. I tries using them but could not work. So wonder if anyone have tried before?

Answer (score 0):

vscode-java extension has a setting called java.import.gradle.user.home. Use this setting to set the GRADLE_USER_HOME. If u are using latest version of vscode-gradle, it also share the same setting.

At current time of writing, do note that java.import.gradle.user.home must be absolute value and does not support variable expansion.

Comment: when I am trying to do that getting error "java.import.gradle.java.home" unknown configuration setting, Any idea?

Comment: i think u should use java.import.gradle.user.home instead of java.import.gradle.java.home, if your intention is to set the path of the folder which will contain your dependencies